# Laravel Blade: The image pointed by the html src attribute isn't compiled within the public directory, unlike the css url property. Why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I must show an `img` html element with `src` pointing to an image that is originally defined within the `resources/images/` folder. So I have written, in my Blade template, the following line (normally it's correct):

```
        <img class="illustration" src="{{ asset('/images/design_7.jpg') }}" alt=""/>
```

Problem : it doesn't work. Indeed, I don't find this image in the directory named `public`.

I've seen that Laravel automatically compiles the image if the latter is pointed by the CSS `url` property. **Why isn't it the case with the html `src` attribute? How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `mix.copyDirectory('resources/<your folder images>', 'public/<your destination folder images>)` in your `webpack.mix.js` file.

(The css compiled images were in fact due to `mix.less(<the css file>, public/<the css destination file>)`)

See 1) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#copying-files-and-directories and 2) https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#working-with-stylesheets